# Openlayers, infer Feature type from FeatureLike

Tags: typescript, openlayers

Modifying a feature emits the following events.

```
import { ModifyEvent } from "ol/interaction/Modify";

type DrawToolEvent {
  type: string
  me: ModifyEvent
  layer: VectorLayer<any>
}
```

And the logic below is executed on the side that subscribes to the DrawToolEvent.

```
this.drawTool.drawEvent.subscribe((e: DrawToolEvent) => {
  if(e.type === 'A') {
    // ...
  } else if(e.type === 'B') {
    // ...
  } else if (e.type === 'C') {
    const featureLike = e.me.features.getArray()[0]
    const clone = featureLike.clone()  // error: Property 'clone' does not exist on type 'FeatureLike'. Property 'clone' does not exist on type 'RenderFeature'.

    // ...
  }
})
```

## Problem

[image]
TypeScript says that `e.me.features.getArray()[0]` returns `FeatureLike` type, but it actually returns `Feature` type when i check through the console.
And it actually works the ways below.

```
// works.
// @ts-ignore
const clone = e.me.features.getArray()[0].clone()

// works.
const clone = (e.me.features.getArray()[0] as Feature<Point>).clone()

// not works.
const clone = e.me.features.getArray()[0].clone()
```

## Question

I don't want to change or ignore the type every time.
Is there a better way to convert type `FeatureLike` into `Feature<T>`?

**ol v6.9.0**

Comment: Where are you getting the type definitions from?  The docs specify it is Feature, not FeatureLike https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Modify.ModifyEvent.html

Comment: @Mike  Added the picture and version

Comment: That was fixed in version 7.2.0 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14194  In earlier versions you will need to typecast to Feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when handling the single click event on map. The target  in callback params is `FeatureLike[]`, but I needed `Feature` to respond the click event.

I cannot find a appropriate way to convert type `FeatureLike` to `Feature` as well. Then I check up the properties and methods that a `FeatureLike` provides. They are as the following

[image]

With those methods, I created new `Feature` to meet my needs. The `getGeometry()` returns `Geometry | RenderFeature | undefined`, which means extra actions requires when create new feature. But it's nothing complex but to force assert the type as `Geometry`. It is works for my case because there aren't many types of objects on the map. More complex use case may require more logic to guard the feature creation step. The code are as below.

```js
...
        if (targetFeature.getGeometry()) {
            setActiveFeature(
              new Feature({
                geometry: targetFeature.getGeometry() as Geometry,
                ...targetFeature.getProperties(),
              }),
              false
            );
          }
...
```

It is not the best practice, it is one can solve my problem though. You can refer to this and hopefully it can give you some inspiration to find the better work around.